# How to move Joomla quick icons to the right side?

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, joomla-3.5, module-display, isis-template

It might not be all that important, but I kinda wish to see the Joomla quick icons on the right. The default setting is on the left, I think?
I attach a screenshot as an example of where I want them to be in Joomla's admin panel.[image]

Comment: Is this question resolved, Gregory? This page appears abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Extensions** > **Modules**, here select **Administrator** in the filter, see the screenshot:

[image]

Just select your module and change inside the position like the front-end modules.

If you go to **administrator/templates/isis/templateDetails.xml** you can see the available positions:

```
<positions>
    <position>menu</position>
    <position>submenu</position>
    <position>toolbar</position>
    <position>title</position>
    <position>status</position>
    <position>icon</position>
    <position>cp_shell</position>
    <position>cpanel</position>
    <position>bottom</position>
    <position>footer</position>
    <position>login</position>
    <position>debug</position>
</positions>
```

If you want, you can add more positions, see this docs:

- [Declaring module positions](https://docs.joomla.org/Declaring_module_positions)

Comment: This is pretty much the correct answer, although it will depend primarily on what Administrator template you use. You can change it just like you do the site template by changing the template scope from "Site" to "Administrator" under Extensions > Templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through CSS as well.  However, your changes may be overwritten in future Joomla releases.

> In administrator/templates/isis/css/template.css

add to bottom:

```
/* Move control panel sidebar to right */
body.com_cpanel .row-fluid [class*="span"] {float:right;}
```